# Continue Looping Through API After Null

Tags: c#, api, restsharp

I'm trying to make an API call to get a list of courses and their version numbers.  In order to do so, I have to Loop through and get each course ID.  Then for each course ID, I have to loop through and get the version numbers.  Many of the courses do not have version numbers, which returns:  "Message": "Version with specified id was not found."  Because my code is expecting an array, It throws the error 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[getCourseVersions+Class2]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly."

My question is this:  How do I force it to continue looping through all the courses after it encounters the "version with the specified id was not found" message?

Here's my code:

```
 public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string CourseType { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Description { get; set; }
    public object Notes { get; set; }
    public object ExternalId { get; set; }
    public object AccessDate { get; set; }
    public int? ExpireType { get; set; }
    public Expireduration ExpireDuration { get; set; }
    public object ExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public int? ActiveStatus { get; set; }
    public string[] TagIds { get; set; }
    public object[] ResourceIds { get; set; }
    public object[] EditorIds { get; set; }
    public object[] Prices { get; set; }
    public object[] CompetencyDefinitionIds { get; set; }
    public object[] PrerequisiteCourseIds { get; set; }
    public object[] PostEnrollmentCourseIds { get; set; }
    public bool? AllowCourseEvaluation { get; set; }
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CertificateUrl { get; set; }
    public object Audience { get; set; }
    public object Goals { get; set; }
    public object Vendor { get; set; }
    public object CompanyCost { get; set; }
    public object LearnerCost { get; set; }
    public object CompanyTime { get; set; }
    public object LearnerTime { get; set; }
}

public class Expireduration
{
    public int? Years { get; set; }
    public int? Months { get; set; }
    public int? Days { get; set; }
    public int? Hours { get; set; }
}


public class Versions
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string VersionNumber { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateAdded { get; set; }
}

//get authorization token from Absorb
private static string GenerateToken()
{
    //do stuff to get authorization token
    return token;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get the generated token
    var strToken = GenerateToken();

    //build API call to get curricula data
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

    var courseClient = new RestClient($"https://urlgoeshere/");
    var courseRequest = new RestRequest("mycourses", Method.GET);
    courseClient.Timeout = 5000;
    courseRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", strToken);
    courseRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var courseResponse = courseClient.Execute(courseRequest);
    var courseContent = courseResponse.Content;

    var Curriculum = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class1>>(courseContent);

    //build API call to get enrooment data for each curriculum
    var enrollmentClient = new RestClient($"https://urlgoeshere/");
    enrollmentClient.Timeout = 5000;

    //loop through each curriculum and get version for each
    foreach (var ro in Curriculum)
    {
        var versionRequest = new RestRequest("courseversions/" + ro.Id, Method.GET);
        versionRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", strToken);
        versionRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        var versionResponse = enrollmentClient.Execute(versionRequest);
        var versionContent = versionResponse.Content;

        //this is where it throws the error
        var versionData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class2>>(versionContent);
        //loop through courses and get versioning information
        foreach (var course in versionData)
        {
            var id = course.Id;
            var courseID = course.CourseId;
            var courseName = course.CourseName;
            var versionNumber = course.VersionNumber;
            var notes = course.Notes;
            var dateAdded = course.DateAdded;

           //display data on page.

            Response.Write("ID: " + id + "<br />");
            Response.Write("CourseID: " + courseID + "<br />");
            Response.Write("Course Name: " + courseName + "<br />");
            Response.Write("Version: " + versionNumber + "<br />");
            Response.Write("Notes: " + notes + "<br />");
            Response.Write("Date Added: " + dateAdded + "<br />");
        }
}
}
```

}

Comment: you can add the code that you want to skip in case of failure inside a try and then in catch do nothing.... that way you can ignore the exception and proceed ahead with your loop... you can also ignore only specific type of errors and throwing exception on the rest of the types

Comment: also... I assume that for the case when you are getting error - the versionContent string type object is empty? if that's the case, why don't you simply just add a string is null or empty check?

Comment: `Goals` seems to be a certain amount, why is it stored as `public object Goals`? Choose your data types wisely

Comment: Just deserialize it first into a type which could hold the error. (or just JObjects) etc Then after filtering the bad content out, store it in final types

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple options here:

1) Check some additional properties in the `versionResponse` value before you try to proceed with the deserialization on the next line. RestSharp provides a number of attributes on the response that may be set in addition to the content that can help tell you that the request failed and you can use that in an if/else block to skip behavior you know will not work.

> You can check the response status to find out if there're any errors.
>   The following properties can tell you about those errors:
>
> - IsSuccessful
> - ResponseStatus
> - StatusCode
> - ErrorMessage
> - ErrorException
>
> It could be that the request was executed and you got 200 OK status code
>   back and some content, but the typed Data property is empty.

http://restsharp.org/get-help/faq.html#empty-response

2) RestSharp can also potentially handle the deserialization itself using the `Execute<T>` method, which will return the object in a strongly typed fashion. You can then customize how RestSharp behaves in a case when the deserialization fails by instructing it to `FailOnDeserialization`, `ThrowOnDeserialization`, or `ThrowOnAnyError` with the corresponding property.

https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Recommended-Usage
http://restsharp.org/usage/exceptions.html